# Yii CActiveForm CheckBox not displayed correctly

Tags: yii, yii-components

I'm new using Yii framework. I show a list a checkbox. But it's not displayed correctly. 
Here is what I want: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/checkboxgood.png

But, here is what I get: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/715/checkbox.png

Anyway, here is code I used to generate this view:

```
  <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'kat3'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'kat3'); ?>
    ?php echo $form->error($model,'kat3'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'kat4'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'kat4'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'kat4'); ?>
    </div>
```

I am new to web developing, and understand CSS a bit. 
Anyone have a suggestion?
thanks! :)

Comment: I dont see any difference except the lable positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii comes with default CSS classes, and that's what you see.

In order to customize these, you must implement your own custom CSS classes for this section. You may wrap your form into a form-class of yours and define the CSS rules as you wish.